# How do I fix this error with wpa_cli? (strace included)

Tags: raspbian-jessie, wpa, fsck

I had an unfortunate pulling of the power plug on my pi and now wpa_cli isn't starting correctly.

```
user@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_cli
wpa_cli v2.3
Copyright (c) 2004-2014, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.



Interactive mode

Could not connect to wpa_supplicant: (null) - re-trying
^Cuser@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I ran `strace wpa_cli -i wlan0` and got a repeating error like the following...

```
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/tmp/wpa_ctrl_1909-24"}, 110) = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
unlink("/tmp/wpa_ctrl_1909-24")         = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {2846, 214746047}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {2846, 215339022}) = 0
select(1, [], [], [], {0, 999407})      = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {2847, 216740204}) = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)         = 3
```

How can I fix this? Does there need to be a `/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0` directory? Is there even a way to run `fsck` on the pi, since there is no 'recovery cd'?

#### Edit(s) for troubleshooting:

I initialized wpa_supplicant using `sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, but then that process takes the terminal window and doesn't let go. Now I'm more confused; I thought that wpa_supplicant started on its own at boot time...

---

```
user@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
user@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
● wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
user@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: is `wpa_supplicant` running? because that's an error you can get if it isn't

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't know. I tried to initialize it and it said `Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant`, but nothing is working yet...

Comment: I don't understand why do you use *wpa_cli*. What operating system you are using?

Comment: @Ingo I'm using standard Raspbian. Jesse I think. [The official docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) call `wpa_cli`... so I figured it was a smart move...

Comment: What gives you `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` and `systemctl status wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service`?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue in a fresh install of Raspbian stretch.  Also, none of the functions in raspi-config which interact with Wi-Fi work, because they fail with the same error ("Could not connect to wpa_supplicant").

Comment: same error, new install